# PostGIS bounding pointcloud to polyhedral

Tags: postgresql, postgis, point-clouds, polyhedra

I have a pointcloud which bounds a true 3D object, is there any way to go from this unstructured pointcloud to a polyhedral? Do I need to mesh/triangulate first?

Does anyone know of a workflow and any functions to do this?

Comment: Similar problem in 2D I've solved with Voronoi polygons, so maybe there's some sort of Voronoi 3D out there...